# Как передать form'е несколько объектов в Java Spring + Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Предположим у меня есть 3 абсолютноо разные сущности (entities):
*- User

- Customer

- Address*

В контролере я пишу так:

```java
@GetMapping
    public ModelAndView registration(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Address address = new Address();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.addObject("address", address);
        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);
        modelAndView.add
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Далее я хочу иметь "доступ" к данным объектам в form'е:

```html
<form th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="user, address, customer" method="POST">
    <label>Имя
        <input type="text" th:field="*{customer.name}" name="email" th:placeholder="name">
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>Фамилия
        <input type="text" th:field="*{customer.surname}" name="email" th:placeholder="surname">
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>Email
        <input type="text" th:field="*{user.email}" name="email" th:placeholder="email">
    </label>
    <br>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

Ошибка указывает на `th:object="user, address, customer"`. Как правильно "вызывать" объекты в форме? Я так же видел (в IDE), что можно сделать через Map, но не знаю как.

### Update 1

Нашел один из вариантов решения: [просто не писать th:object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122257/how-to-pass-two-objects-to-use-in-a-form-using-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взятый за основу ответ: [сссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122853/8992586)

Один из вариантов (рабочий):
**Не использовать** в форме `th:object`, а просто передавать значения через `th:field` или (как предлагает автор ответа) `th:value`.

Пример кода:

```html
<label>Имя
        <input type="text" th:field="*{customer.name}" name="name" th:placeholder="name">
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>Фамилия
        <input type="text" th:field="*{customer.surname}" name="surname" th:placeholder="surname">
    </label>
    <br>
```

Дополнительные примеры кода:

```java
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView registration(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Address address = new Address();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.addObject("address", address);
        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

```java
    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, Address address, Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(address);
        System.out.println(customer);
        System.out.println("______");
        System.out.println("______");
    return modelAndView;
}
```